# How to use facebook api to pull user data

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I have a requirement in our sign up screen wherein we ask the user if they want to use their facebook profile for sign up. The process we are thinking is when the user logs in facebook or allow us to access their data. I will just pull the name, e-mail, address and save those things in our database as in creating an account base on their facebook data.

I'm confused on how to start it so does anybody can point me or have sample code how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you telling me that you never found a sample code for this?

Comment: mostly are php. In a way I'm trying to find a documentation. Maybe if you will try to help instead of being sarcastic then this world will be much better.

Comment: Sorry.. my connection got screwed up before completing the comment and it was posted somehow and couldn't. Have you checked? http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ .

Comment: Forgiven. :) I've used it but as I mentioned what we need is the facebook connect button and I need the facebook to display the page where it ask for permission. Because currently it just login directly.